# ip_conntrack_ftp inside LXC

Tags: iptables, ftp, nat, lxc, proftpd

- ProFTPd instance on a LXC container behind NAT
- LXC container is using bridged networking
- `PassivePorts 60000 61000` has been defined in proftpd.conf
- `nf_nat_ftp` and `nf_conntrack_ftp` loaded on the *host* running the container
- iptables inside the container contains

  ```
  -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
  ```

Why does `Passive mode` only work when I explicitly open passive ports with

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 60000:61000 -j ACCEPT
```

? Shouldn't this be automatically managed by the `nf_conntrack_ftp` helper module?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the problem that after installing lxc together with a new version of the linux kernel needed, the connection tracker helpers stopped working. 
This, however, was not a problem of lxc but a problem of the kernel and I could get around it by adding

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1
```

to sysctl.conf. Apparently newer kernels after 4.7 have [better ways](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/) to configure the helpers (and probably using them would be a better answer to this question) and therefore net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=0 is the default now, see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369489).

Comment: Same here, with kernel 4.15.18-9-pve. Many thanks !